# Why won't my storyboard work on the iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard

In the app delegate I have this written to determine which storyboard will be opened depending on the screen size,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [self grabStoryboard];

// show the storyboard
self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}

- (UIStoryboard *)grabStoryboard {

UIStoryboard *storyboard;

// detect the height of our screen
int width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

if (width == 480) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iphone4" bundle:nil];
    // NSLog(@"Device has a 3.5inch Display.");
} else {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    // NSLog(@"Device has a 4inch Display.");
}

return storyboard;
}
```

The app opens landscape on the device.
This will properly choose between a 3.5 inch device and a 4 inch device in the simulators, but won't properly display in an actual 3.5 inch device. In Xcode 6 it opens the correct storyboard for the 4s or the 5, 6 ,6+ depending on the width of the screen but when tested on an actual Iphone 4s (with ios 7.1.1) the storyboard configured for 4 inch devices is displayed.

Comment: This is a bad strategy anyway - The support for split screen modes in iOS9 shows how it is becoming increasingly difficult to design for specific hardware dimensions.  You are better off adopting size classes and autolayout

Comment: Yeah we obviously plan on doing that from now on. Why does it work in the simulator but not on the device though?

Comment: it works just fine in the simulator but not on the actual iphone 4.. all I'm asking is why.

Comment: What width is being reported?  Have you logged or set a breakpoint to examine it?

Comment: Thanks for the input Paul! We got it fixed after closer examination. Definitely plan on using autolayout on the next project multiple storyboards and such is a mess.